# Apply curve on video

Tags: jquery, video, jquery-plugins, html5-video, video.js

I'm using videojs 3.2.0 plugin to play video. I've set curve border around the video so video is over come from the border and looks not good. I want to curve video and its control bar as per the border, how can I do that ?

Comment: Could you please provide an example code for that? You can use a service like http://jsfiddle.net to share it easily if you prefer

Comment: Hi jmserra, Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/Aj4UB/

Comment: Check the corners of the video and controller, you'll get idea what's the exact thing I want to do.

Comment: Was the answer helpful to you? if so consider accepting it, otherwise tell us what's wrong with it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply a radius to the whole video, you should add the properties to the video.js elements itself,

[Here's the working example at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uAWzQ/)

Here's the added CSS:

```
#example_video_1,.vjs-controls,.video-js,.vjs-poster{
    border-radius:5px;
}
.vjs-controls{
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;    
}
```